# Taghelpers : Is it possible to add type constraints to a ModelExpression?

Tags: constraints, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

With htmlhelpers it is possible to constrain what types your helper will bind to

```
public static HtmlString DatePicker<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
                                            Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression) 
{
    //CODE
}
```

or

```
public static HtmlString DatePicker<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
                                            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    where TProperty : DateTime 
{
    //CODE
}
```

Do tag helpers allow constraints? If so could anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is really the same concept in this case - you can specify tag helpers attach to a specific html target element using `[HtmlTargetElement]`, but generally you will be using `ModelExpression` to bind to a model's property.

None of the built in tag helpers use type constraints so I suspect you may be battling the framework somewhat - You are setting properties on the class, so unless the tag-helper itself is generic you would not be able to have a generic property anyway.